# Java: replace multiple string patterns from one string value

Tags: java, regex, foreach, pattern-matching

I'm struggling to get this working.

I have a regex pattern as: `".*(${.*}).*"`

And a string variable `myVar = "name = '${userName}' / pass = '${password}'"`

I have a hashmap which stores values, in this case "${userName}" would have a value of "John Doe" and "${password}" would have a value of "secretpwd".

How can I loop all found matches in myVar (in this case "userName" and "password")?
Then I could loop each match found and request their corresponding value from the hashmap.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use e.g. the following code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{.*?\\}");
while (true) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(myVar);
    if (!m.find()) {
        break;
    }
    String variable = m.group();
    String rep = hash.get(variable);
    myVar = m.replaceFirst(rep);
}
```

Note that I adjusted the regular expression to fit your requirements.

Comment: Maybe your hash contains a value looking like `${...}`? I can't say without knowing your input and your hash content. You may include a debug output or put a break point just in the last line and look for `variable` and `rep` each time.

Comment: The loop keeps returning the same regexp match (userName), it doesn't loop trough each match. so if I have `"username = '${userName}' and password= = '${password}'"` it loops and outputs (debug): `variable = ${userName}
rep = John Doe` so it's correct but just keeps looping and outputing that and never the ${password} one

Comment: Stupid me, forgot to type the m.replace() in the code, and they say copy/paste is bad practice! :)

Answer (score 0):

With this string as regexp, you'll have 2 groups containing "${user}" and "${password}" :

```
".*(\\$\\{.*}).*(\\$\\{.*}).*"
```

To iterate through the groups :

```
// Compile and use regular expression
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
boolean matchFound = matcher.find();

if (matchFound) {
    // Get all groups for this match
    for (int i=0; i<=matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        String groupStr = matcher.group(i);
    }
}
```

source : http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util.regex/Group.html

Comment: The string can contain 0 to n variables, therefore the reg exp doesn't fit my requirements. Will check the link for help. Thanks